# Regular language is closed given transposition of rightmost character to leftmost

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata

It would appear straightforward to show that a regular language is closed given the transposition of the rightmost character to the front. However after drawing a few sample DFA for the phenomenon, I've been unable to come up with a generalized 'concept' or 'proof'  that shows it's true for all regular languages. Could anyone help me out? It's on occasions like these that I see the value of formal definitions for DFA (instead of just drawings), however it's been a while since I've studied those.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the transposed language never contains the empty string.

Let $L$ be a regular language, say accepted by a DFA with states $Q$, initial state $q_0$, accepting states $F$, and transition function $\delta$.

We construct a new DFA with states $Q' = q'_0 \cup (Q \times \Sigma)$. The initial state of the new DFA is $q'_0$. The transition function is defined as follows: $\delta'(q'_0,\sigma) = (q_0,\sigma)$, and $\delta'((q,\sigma),\tau) = (\delta(q,\tau),\sigma)$. Finally, the set of accepting states $F'$ contains all states $(q,\sigma)$ such that $\delta(q,\sigma) \in F$.

The new DFA reads the first symbol $\sigma$ and remembers it. It then simulates the original DFA, accepting a word if adding $\sigma$ would result in the original DFA accepting it.

Comment: Hi Yuval, sorry I'm only just getting back to you. I don't understand what new states you are denoting by $Q \times \Sigma$.

Comment: This is a Cartesian product. You can look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: No, I understand that. But how is $(q, \sigma)$ a \emph{state} for any $q \in Q$, $\sigma \in \Sigma$?

Comment: It is a state of the new automaton *by definition*.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try solving this question ,

The basic idea is that we need to remember the first symbol we read  $\alpha$ , then we begin our computation from the start state and the second symbol , once we finish we arrive at a state q , if there is a transition from q to an accept state on $\alpha$ we accept

So , we have a DFA M that accepts a language L , we want to construct M' to accept the transposed language L'

In M' we begin in a new start state $q_0'$

Now for each $\alpha \in \Sigma$ we make a copy of M , name it $M_\alpha$ , so when we are in $q_0'$ and we read a symbol $\alpha$ we go to the start state of $M_\alpha$

Formally , $\delta(q_0',\alpha) = q_{0_{\alpha}}$

Now how is each $M_\alpha$ different from the original M ?

$M_\alpha$ is the same as M , all we have to change is the set of accept states , the new accept states are the states who have a transition on $\alpha$ to accept state ,

So let $F_\alpha$ be the set of accept states for $M_\alpha$ , if in M a rule exist $\delta(q,\alpha) = q_{accept}$ , then $q_\alpha \in F_\alpha$ (here q in M corresponds to $q_\alpha$ in $M_\alpha$ )

The other answer provided earlier is the same idea expressed more formally (sorry to provide another answer when it is the same idea , could not fit all this into a comment !!!)